# PowerShell - Adding appendix to files when renaming with the same name

Tags: powershell

so this will be used to rename and move certificates for wiped hard drives. Most computers/laptops have just a single drive, so there will be just a single file. But servers and some pc/laptops will have more that 1 drive, so there will be multiple files. I need to rename all of them with the new name, which is the numbering we use - lets say 34567890. So lets say I have 3 files in that directory, i need to rename them to 34567890, 34567890 (1), 34567890 (2) and move them to the storage folder.
I got the most of it done, but I can't figure out how to rename when I have multiple files. Here is my code:

```
$name= Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Scan ID"
$ext='.pdf'
$fullname=$name+$ext
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\kd\cert\ -Recurse -File | Rename-Item -NewName $fullname
If(Get-Childitem -Path C:\Intel\ -Filter $fullname)
{
    Write-host "SCAN ID EXISTS"
}
Elseif((Get-ChildItem -Path D:\kd\cert\ -Force | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0)
{
    Write-host "FOLDER IS EMPTY! REPORT WAS NOT COPIED!!!"
}
Else
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path D:\kd\cert\ -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination C:\Intel
    Write-host "Certificate copied!"
}
```

I believe it has to be done with ForEach-Object, but i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if I understood the requirement completely but if I got it right something like this could be a starting point.

```
$ScanID = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Scan ID'
$SourceFolder = 'D:\kd\cert'
$DesinationFolder = 'C:\Intel'
$Extension = '.pdf'

$Counter = 0
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Recurse -File |
    ForEach-Object {
        $TargetFileName = '{0}_{1:d3}{2}' -f $ScanID, $Counter, $Extension
        $TargetPath = Join-Path -Path $DesinationFolder -ChildPath $TargetFileName
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $TargetPath
        $Counter++
    }
```

The target file name is created via the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.4#format-operator--f) `-f` combining the variables `$ScanID`, `$Counter` and `$Extension`. The filename is then combined with the destination directory to a full path.
And the rename and the move operation is done at once with `Move-Item`. ‍♂️

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, it works perfect.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it helped. 